# React child (found: object with keys {}) won't render file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Keep getting an error while trying to export Ids:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to
> render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
>  8 |     )
>  9 |   }
> 10 | 
> 11 | ReactDOM.render(<Ids />, document.getElementById("root"))
> 12 | export default Ids
```

expanded:

```
  156 | }
  157 | 
  158 | _c = Ids;
> 159 | react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.render( /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["jsxDEV"])(Ids, {}, void 0, false, {
      |                                                  ^  160 |   fileName: _jsxFileName,
  161 |   lineNumber: 11,
  162 |   columnNumber: 17
```

This is my `index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tester from "./Tester.js"

ReactDOM.render(<Tester />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

This is my `Apps.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Apps(name) {

    return( <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>

    )
  }
  
ReactDOM.render(<Apps />, document.getElementById("root"))
export default Apps
```

This is my `Ids.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Ids(id) {

    return( <h1>id = {id}</h1>

    )
  }

ReactDOM.render(<Ids />, document.getElementById("root"))
export default Ids
```

This is my `Tester.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Ids from './Ids.js';
import Apps from './Apps.js';

function Tester(){
    const Apps = "Jenny"
    const Ids = 2

    return(
    <div>
        <Apps />
        <Ids />
    </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Tester
    name ={Apps.name}
    id ={Ids.id}
/>,
document.getElementById("root")
)
export default Tester
```

Thank you! If it's not a syntax error please just send me hints as I want to find out the error by myself, but have difficulty finding it since it has no error for `Apps.js` but it has errors for `Ids.js`

Comment: I do think your Ids variable and your Ids component will clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one ReactDom.render

React component based on tree structure:
[image]

---

```
  const Apps = "Jenny"
  const Ids = 2

<Tester
    name ={Apps.name}
    id ={Ids.id}
/>,
```

You can't pass **Apps.name** - cause this is **string** not **object** - the same with Ids.

Change to:

```
<Tester
    name ={Apps}
    id ={Ids}
/>,
```

or:

```
const Apps = {
  name: 'Jenny'
}
        
const Ids = {
  id: 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the ReactDom and passing strings

Comment: Although I have no errors anymore, it does not print out any of my Tester values... My Tester is set up like this: function Tester(){ const Apps = ''Jenny" return (<div> <Apps /></div>)}.    and the render is: <Tester name = {Apps}

Comment: Just see How to pass and print components - U Can use destructure them or pass by props

Answer (score 1):

You must use `ReactDOM.render` only once (for the root element).

Then you need to read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to see how to pass properties to a react component.

`function Apps(name){...}` will not work, you should either write :

- `function Apps(props){ // use props.name to get the name property }`
- `function Apps({name}) { // use the name property }`

Basically, you must have

`index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tester from "./Tester.js"

ReactDOM.render(<Tester />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

`Tester.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Ids from './Ids.js';
import Apps from './Apps.js';

function Tester(props){
    return(
      <div>
        <Apps name={props.name}/>
        <Ids id={props.id}/>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Tester
```

`Apps.js`

```
import React from 'react';

function Apps(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>
}
  
export default Apps
```

`Ids.js`

```
import React from 'react';

function Ids({id}) {
  return <h1>id = {id}</h1>
}

export default Ids
```